# How to correctly create a multi input neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

i'm building a NN that has, as input, two car images and classifies if thery are the same make and model. My problem is in the `fit`method of keras, because there is this error

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

The network architecture is the following:

```
input1=Input((150,200,3))
model1=InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input1)
model1.layers.pop()
input2=Input((150,200,3))
model2=InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input2)
model2.layers.pop()
for layer in model2.layers:
  layer.name = "custom_layer_"+ layer.name
concat = concatenate([model1.layers[-1].output,model2.layers[-1].output])
flat = Flatten()(concat)
dense1=Dense(100, activation='relu')(flat)
do1=Dropout(0.25)(dense1)
dense2=Dense(50, activation='relu')(do1)
do2=Dropout(0.25)(dense2)
dense3=Dense(1, activation='softmax')(do2)
model = Model(inputs=[model1.input,model2.input],outputs=dense3)
```

My idea is that the error is due to the `to_catogorical` method that i have called on the array which stores, as 0 or 1, if the two cars have the same make and model or not. Any suggestion?

Comment: What happens if you pass the target as `np.array([1,0,1,.....])`just as a 1D list.

Comment: there is this error:


```ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (10000, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes).```

Comment: try using `loss=sigmoid`

Comment: `sigmoid` isn't an activation function?

Comment: sorry my bad, you are training a siamese network. You need to fix the architechture i.e. you should have a base model. Refer this: https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/

Comment: Ok, let me try this solution.

Comment: I'm reading about the siamese network, and I have to provide a function to evaluate the difference between the two images, because of the picture are not equal (a side picture with a frontal picture) which function do you suggest me? An euclidean distance should not be so accurate with picture taken from different side, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing binary classification with one-hot encoded labels, then you should change this line:

```
dense3=Dense(1, activation='softmax')(do2)
```

To:

```
dense3=Dense(2, activation='softmax')(do2)
```

Softmax with a single neuron makes no sense, two neurons should be used for binary classification with softmax activation.

Comment: because the last layer needs a number of neurons equal to the number of classes?

Comment: @thenoobdeveloper With a softmax activation yes

Comment: ok thanks, it works. Do you think that this is a good approach to solve my problem?

Comment: @thenoobdeveloper That is impossible to answer and not a programming issue